# Limit $\lim_{x\to2^+}x{\sqrt{x-1}\over\sqrt{x-2}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am having problems with this  limit problem, I tried to rationalize and keep getting that the limit is $∞$ but in the book the answer is $2$, am I making a mistake here ?

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} x\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-2}}$$

Comment: Is this exactly what your book says?

Comment: The limit is $\infty$, not $2$.  Are you certain that you have it correct?

Comment: Yes, the answer clearly states 2. It is a mistake then. I keep getting $∞$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to2^+}x{\sqrt{x-1}\over\sqrt{x-2}}=\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{0^+}\right)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $+\infty$ it of the form ${2\over 0}$